# Py4JJavaError when attempting to write a spark dataframe in json format

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark, anaconda

I would greatly appreciate some help on the following problem. I use anaconda on Windows 10. I have created an enviroment, I have imported pyspark in order to work with some transformations in Apache Spark. But, when I try to write a dataframe on my disk in json format I receive an Py4JJaveError.
Below a piece of my code:

```
import pyspark
import os
import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8"
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('paris').getOrCreate()
data = [{'Brand': 'Toyota','Model': 'Corolla','Rate': 14.52,'Days': 7},{'Brand':'Volvo','Model': 'V40','Rate': 24.2,'Days': 2}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.write.format('json').mode('overwrite').save('json-example')
```

I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 2
      1 # 
----> 2 df.write.format('json').mode('overwrite').save('json-example')

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Spark1\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:740, in     DataFrameWriter.save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    738     self._jwrite.save()
    739 else:
--> 740     self._jwrite.save(path)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Spark1\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in     JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Spark1\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    109 def deco(*a, **kw):
    110     try:
--> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
    112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Spark1\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer,     gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o52.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

I have tried different versions of python and Spark  but the problem persists.
Some information about my system:

```
spark.version=3.2.4
pyspark.version=3.2.1
python.version=3.9.11
```